# Why did the `READ TIMESERIES` cannot query to read data in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I already set `root.tonglian` in Apache IoTDB to `READ TIMESERIES` status, but when I tried to query using `select * from root.tonglian.12order_queue.300729SZ.OrderQty33` statement, but the IoTDB server still reported that this time series does not have the permission to read the data. Anyone know where should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path of `READ TIMESERIES` setting in Apache IoTDB needs to be configured using `GRANT USER read user PRIVILEGES READ TIMESERIES on root.tonglian.**` command. Then you should be able to perform the `select YieldToMatu from root.tonglian.l2ticks.688072SH` query.